# Expand woocommerce_created_customer hook for custom data

Tags: php, woocommerce

How can I expand the below to handle customer details into the email like a specific name or detail in the email? or even make it load a specific template etc:

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'admin_email_on_registration', 10 , 1);
function admin_email_on_registration( $customer_id) {
    wp_new_user_notification( $customer_id );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual hook on which you are working is as follows:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated );
```

So little modification in your function like

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'admin_email_on_registration', 10 , 3);
function admin_email_on_registration( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated) {
    wp_new_user_notification( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated );
}
```

Using the current hook 'woocommerce_created_customer' you can access the following details only.

`$new_customer_data` contains `'user_login' => $username, 'user_pass'  => $password, 'user_email' => $email,    'role'       => 'customer'` in an array.

For loading a specific template view `wrap_message()` of woocommerce.